# Python Turtle File "<string>", line 5, in penup

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am using Python 3.10 and have the following code block. I added a line to change the title and had the same kind of message but I've since removed it and now am getting this message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Documents\project.py", line 20, in <module>
    drawTarget(turtle, radius)
  File "Documents\project.py", line 14, in drawTarget
    turtle.penup()
  File "<string>", line 5, in penup
turtle.Terminator
```

Below is a sample of my code.

```
import turtle

circleRadius = 100

turtle.tracer(False)

turtle.hideturtle()

turtle.tracer(True)

turtle.mainloop()

def drawTarget(turtle, radius):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.sety(-radius)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(radius, steps=90)

for radius in range(circleRadius, 500, circleRadius):
    drawTarget(turtle, radius)
```

I now have no strings anywhere in my script. If I remove the offending line, it simply throws the same error for the line below on the `sety` method call.

Comment: Can you share the whole error and stacktrace?

Comment: Please show the full error you're getting in the console

Comment: Added full error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `turtle.mainloop()` before the function.The Terminator Error occurs when the turtle screen has been closed but function is still acting as if it's running.
Change as follows:

```
import turtle

circleRadius = 100

turtle.tracer(False)

turtle.hideturtle()

turtle.tracer(True)

def drawTarget(turtle, radius):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.sety(-radius)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(radius, steps=90)

for radius in range(circleRadius, 500, circleRadius):
    drawTarget(turtle, radius)
turtle.mainloop()
```